# Column count doesn't match value count

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, runtime-error

Can anyone see why this SQL string would throw up the "Column count doesn't match value count" error?

```
    SQL = ("INSERT INTO partners_customers(account_name,address1,city,postcode,parent_partners_acc,parent_partners_id) _
    VALUES ('" & newcustname.Text & "','" & newcustaddress.Text & "','" & newcustcity.Text & "," & newcustpostcode.Text & "," & Home.activeuser & "," & Home.activeuserid & "'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
```

As far as i can see its 6 columns and 6 values.

Its driving me mad :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the last 3 values you are missing the single quotes. Formatting the code helps you find these types of issues:

```
SQL = ("
INSERT INTO partners_customers (
    account_name,
    address1,
    city,
    postcode,
    parent_partners_acc,
    parent_partners_id
) _
VALUES
    (
        '" & newcustname. TEXT & "',
        '" & newcustaddress. TEXT & "',
        '" & newcustcity. TEXT & "',
        '" & newcustpostcode. TEXT & "',
        '" & Home.activeuser & "',
        '" & Home.activeuserid & "'
    );

SELECT
    LAST_INSERT_ID()
");
```

Comment: Spot on! how I didn't see that before I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing at least one single quotes:
 and possibly more depending on the data types of the other columns
    SQL = ("INSERT INTO partners_customers     (account_name,address1,city,postcode,parent_partners_acc,parent_partners_id) _
        VALUES ('" & newcustname.Text & "','" & newcustaddress.Text & "','" &     newcustcity.Text & "'," & newcustpostcode.Text & "," & Home.activeuser & "," &     Home.activeuserid & "'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")